# iPhone went through wash - charging flashligh comes on

Tags: iphone, itunes

Someone, please help me I really don't want to buy a new iPhone! Also it isn't recognised by iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you able to power on the device after making sure that it's sufficiently dried.

In case the device isn't powering, unfortunately, there's nothing much you can do. [Liquid damage to iPhone or iPod isn't covered by warranty](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204104).

Still, it would be advisable to get in touch with authorised service personnel to check for the extent of damage and to evaluate recovery options.